# aria-live="polite" not reading roles of elements it is associated with

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a site that needs to be made fully accessible. We have dynamic content that sits on a single page (doesn't reload) and changes on the screen.

For the screen-reader to keep up with this, I've added some JS logic where the attribute `aria-hidden="true"` or `aria-live= "polite"` is added to hide and reveal the targeted elements.

Although the element's `aria-label` is read out, I run into an issue where the `role` attribute is left out.

**Situation 1**

`<div role="button" aria-label="This is a label" aria-hidden="true"></div>`

I use JS to remove the attribute `aria-hidden` and add `aria-live="polite"` when this button needs to be read on the page

Which makes the screen-reader then read **"This is a label"**

**Situation 2**

`<div role="button" aria-label="This is a label"></div>`

However, if the content is read from the get-go without being hidden, i.e. no `aria-hidden="true"` it reads as **"This is a label, Button"**

I want this behaviour, but with me able to control when this occurs.

I'm using iOS screen reader on the latest Chrome.

I've tried quite a few hacks to get around this:

- Setting `aria-hidden="true"` to parent and indivdual
  elements results in role still being omitted
- Not using `aria-live="polite"` to reveal but the opposite
  `aria-hidden="false"`. This however won't even get picked up by the
  screen-reader

Any help or guidance much appreciated.

Additional JSFiddle, with a simplified example (you can use Apple screenreader and click into the window to hear the content read):

https://jsfiddle.net/qf4jv6g9/2/

Comment: I don't well understand in which case it says "button", and in which case it doesn't. Can you provide the code for both cases or explain a little more ? Also, please indicate which screen reader, browser and OS you used for your test. Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to fix a problem the wrong way perhaps? If you have dynamically loaded pages focus management is what you need. If this is for loading new pages [this answer I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63889961/2702894) is likely the pattern you need to follow. If that isn't the case then can you add more details as @QuentinC suggested so we can help you further. A fiddle demonstrating the problem would be really useful!

Comment: @QuentinC I cleared it up a bit more. Let me know if that makes more sense.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Thanks for the response, I've edited my OG Q. To clarify, I'm not loading new pages. It all exists on a single page but is hidden from view and revealed when a user needs to see it. Let me know if that makes more sense!

Comment: Sometimes the simplest fixes are best, instead of `<div role="button"` just use a `<button>`. It will be announced consistently. As you can style buttons any way you want nowadays it will be 100 times easier.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Ahhh, I will give that a go. We are dealing with old code that had reasonings for utilizing `<divs>` instead of buttons. Although it is simpler, it will require refactoring some other aspects. I will look into it, thanks for the help!

Comment: That's definitely better reworded. +1 you should definitely use `<button>` instead of `<div>`. Also, be careful that adding aria-live to an existing element doesn't make it announced everywhere, the only cases where it is 100% guaranteed is 1/adding a new element with aria-live in the DOM and 2/changing the content of an element that already has aria-live.
Finally, on iOS and mac you should use Safari because that's what almost all VoiceOver users have anyway; this might make a big difference in what you observe at the end.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I've come back to this problem after quite a few tries. I've provided a simplified JSFiddle that emulates the problem despite using <button> tags instead of <div>, are either of you aware of this as a limitation with accessibility in regards to dynamic content? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right so `aria-live` should sit on a **container** element, not on the element itself. So when you change the content of an element with `aria-live` it will read the content. On your button, you have set it as `aria-live` so it is trying to read its content. Essentially you have broken the button! Wrap the button in a `<div>` with `aria-live` and see if that works (and remove the `aria-live` from the button itself!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the comments are decent so far but are avoiding the problem.  Whether you use a real `<button>` or `<div role="button">` doesn't matter.  Using a `<div>` is certainly a lot more work because you need `tabindex` and event handlers and `aria-label` and such, but if all that is there, it doesn't matter to assistive technology which one you use.

Regarding `aria-live`, it's not meant to be a dynamic property.  That is, it's not an attribute you want to add on the fly.  It works best when the page is loaded and the element already has `aria-live` set.

The purpose of `aria-live` is to announce changes to the element (or child elements if `aria-live` is set on a container).  So when the page is loaded and the right elements have aria-live, then anytime you add text to the element (or child element) or add/remove child elements or hide/unhide child elements, those changes will be announced.  But only the **text** is announced.  (See [`aria-relevant`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-relevant) to control what types of changes are announced.)

You can run into timing issues if you dynamically add an element with `aria-live` and then add child elements to that new live region.  Should the newly added children be announced right then or does the display/refresh cycle need to go through once before the "live-ness" takes affect?  It's hard to say because browsers and operating systems combinations work a little differently.

What I **have** found is that aria-live works fantastic when I'm not dynamically adding that attribute.

Your fiddle example does not work at all with NVDA on a PC.  That is, nothing is announced when the new button is revealed, which is what I expect because you're unhiding a button **and** adding `aria-live` to it.  So I think the purpose of `aria-live` is a little misunderstood.  If you add a container around the hidden button and that container has `aria-live`, then when the button is unhidden, it'll be announced.

I changed your fiddle to have:

```
<div aria-live="polite">
  <button aria-hidden="true" class="newButton hidden" role="button">
    New Content
  </button>
</div>
```

and I changes the JS to remove the `aria-live` line

```js
     activeButton.addEventListener('click',function testFunc() {
        //newButton.setAttribute("aria-live","polite");
        newButton.removeAttribute("aria-hidden");
        newButton.classList.remove("hidden");
      }
```

Now when I click on the "reveal" button, I hear "new content".  I **don't** hear "button" but that's ok.  `aria-live` is meant to announce text changes, not the role of elements.